# How to filter observable array?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the following observable arrays:

```
const stages = [
{Id: 1, Name: "First stage", RoleId: 71},
{Id: 2, Name: "Second stage", RoleId: 72},
{Id: 3, Name: "Third stage", RoleId: 73}];

const roles = [
{Id: 71, Name: "Stuff", Key: "STF"},
{Id: 72, Name: "Manager", Key: "MGR"},
{Id: 73, Name: "CEO", Key: "CEO"}];
```

So I have the `"MGR"` key and I want to get observable of `stages` where `RoleId` is equal to manager's role.

They are two observables: stages and roles. I have read about `combineLatest` method which is possible might help me, but I do not know how to filter combined result.

```
const filteredStages = stages.combineLatest(roles, (s, r) => ({
    s: s,
    r: r
}))
.filter(x => ?);
```

What is the right way to get filtered stages?

Comment: Do you want to merge the results, `stage + role` in a single object?

Comment: Do you really need to use Observables for this? I mean `stages` and `roles` are arrays, Observables emitting arrays or Observable emitting each item separately?

Comment: @IsaacFerreira No. I only need to get obsevable of array where stages contains `RoleId: 72`, but this role id I get by using `"MGR"` key from roles observable.

Comment: @martin They come to me from redux state. So I have two observable: stages and roles. Actually they are arrays of models. I want to get filtered array of stages where `RoleId` is equal to 72 and this array should be wrapped up in observable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So finally I solved my issue. I did it by using `map` function.

```
const key = 'MGR';

const filteredStages = stages.combineLatest(roles,
(s, r) => ({
   s,
   r
})).map(x => {
    const managerRole = x.r.find(role => role.LookupKey === key);

    return x.s.filter(stage => stage.RoleId !== managerRole.Id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `role.Id` won't be changed:

```
stages.filter(stage => stage.RoleId === 72)
```

If `role.Id` might be changed later:

```
const manager = roles.find(role => role.Key === "MGR");

stages.filter(stage => stage.RoleId === manager.Id)
```

Comment: `stages` is observable of array. It means that `stages.filter(s => ...);` s will be `StageModel[]`.

Comment: `stages.filter()` will return `Stage[]`.

Comment: I am talking that `stage` variable inside `filter` statement will an array because `const stages` is `Observable<StageModel[]>`. This array do not has `RoleId` property. Each element of this array has this property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the ids in the array from the roles$ stream and then switchmap to the stages$ stream for all stages with a matching id:

```
return roles$.pipe(
  switchMap(roles => {
    let ids = roles.filter(role => role.Key === 'MGR').map(role => role.Id);

    return stage$.pipe(
      filter(stage => ids.indexOf(stage.Id) > -1),
    );
  })
);
```

Comment: `[ts] Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable<RoleModel[]>'.`

Answer (score 0):

*This is using Rxjs version 5 syntax*

I think it would be wise to create another observable of the Role you want to filter by. Below I've just done this by filtering by the Key property.

```
const stages$ = Observable.of([
   {Id: 1, Name: "First stage", RoleId: 71},
   {Id: 2, Name: "Second stage", RoleId: 72},
   {Id: 3, Name: "Third stage", RoleId: 73}]);

const roles$ = Observable.of([
   {Id: 71, Name: "Stuff", Key: "STF"},
   {Id: 72, Name: "Manager", Key: "MGR"},
   {Id: 73, Name: "CEO", Key: "CEO"}];

const selectedRole$ = roles$.filter((roles) => {
    return roles.filter(r => r.Key === "MGR");
});

const filteredStages$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  stages$,
  selectedRole$,
  (stagesArr, role) => {
     return stagesArr.filter(s => s.Id === role.Id)
  })
  .subscribe((filteredStages) => console.log('stages', filteredStages);
```

Comment: I don't understand how you call `Key` property inside this statement `const selectedRole$ = roles$.filter((r) => r.Key === "MGR"));` Because `r` is an array and does not contain `Key` property.

Comment: r is an individual object within roles$ array. Works the same as JavaScript array filter

Comment: Visual Studio Code gives me the following error message: `[ts] Property 'Key' does not exist on type '{ Id: number; Name: string; Key: string; }[]'. Did you mean 'keys'?`

Comment: Are you able to replicate your project setup in a stackblitz? I'm happy to help more.

Comment: You were right. I have edited the selectedRole$ output to use filter on the array itself.